# Complex integration with Cauchy formula II

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to compute the following integral:
$$\int_{C^{+}} \frac{\text{Log}(z)}{(z+1)(z+2)^2}dz$$
where $C^{+}$ is the circle with center $z=-2$ and radius $3/2$.

I suppose that I have to use Cauchy integral formula but I am lost.

Comment: And what is $\operatorname{Log}$?

Comment: Since the other pieces of the integrand do not have singularities within the circle, consider thinking of this as $$\int_{C^+} \frac{f(z)}{(z-(-2))^2}\:dz$$ Does this remind you of anything?

Comment: But, is Log(z)/(z+1) analytic on this region? We have a singularity at $z=-1$ which is inside the circle...

Comment: Oh yes, I misread the radius. I have a way around that which I am typing up as an answer.

Comment: That is the problem I find. I dont know how to overcome it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use partial fraction decomposition to get that

$$\int_{C^+} \frac{\log z}{(z+1)(z+2)^2}\:dz = \int_{C^+} \frac{\log z}{z+1}\:dz - \int_{C^+} \frac{\log z}{z+2}\:dz - \int_{C^+} \frac{\log z}{(z+2)^2}\:dz$$

Now what can you do for each individual piece? (Amazingly, this answer will be independent of choice of branch cut)

Comment: Now it is easy using Cauchy integral formulas, thank you very much!!!!